# How to deal with keys not found in Python Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, text-processing

I have the following code:

```
from math import sqrt
from collections import Counter

def forSearch():
    words = {'bit':{1:3,2:4,3:19,4:0},'shoe':{1:0,2:0,3:0,4:0},'dog':{1:3,2:0,3:4,4:5}, 'red':{1:0,2:0,3:15,4:0}}
    search = {'bit':1,'dog':3,'shoe':5}
num_files = 4

    file_relevancy = Counter()
    c = sqrt(sum([x**2 for x in search.values()]))
    for i in range(1, num_files+1):
        words_ith_val = [words[x][i] for x in search.keys() ]
        a = sum([search[key] * words[key][i] for key in search.keys()])
        b = sqrt(sum([x**2 for x in words_ith_val]))
        file_relevancy[i] = (a / (b * c))

    return [x[0] for x in file_relevancy.most_common(num_files)]

print forSearch()
```

However, this has a problem with words which are contained in search but not in words:

I want to say something like this here:

```
for i in range(1, num_files+1):
    if corresponding key in words cannot be found
        insert it and make its value = 0
    words_ith_val = [words[x][i] for x in search.keys() ]
```

Then it should work?

Unless anyone else has any better suggestions?

Comment: Your declaration of `words` variable should be able to use array syntax: `words = {'bit': [3,4,19,0], 'shoe': [0,0,0,0], 'dog': [3,0,4]}. And you probably want to stick with 0-index (counting starts at 0, not 1)

Comment: I am not allowed to change the way words is.

Answer (score 2):

[`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
import collections

D = collections.defaultdict(int)
D['foo'] = 42
print D['foo'], D['bar']
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
```

This will initialize a dictionary where the keys are created on access and the default value is 0. You can use other types as well:

```
defaultdict(dict)
defaultdict(list)
```

They will be initialized with an empty dictionary/list.
You can also overwrite the default value with a factory method. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict for details.

Comment: This problem is simplified, I have to use the dictionary words, and in that format.

Answer (score 0):

What about this code:

```
if key not in words:
    words[key] = {k+1: 0 for k in range(num_files)}
```

In your code you can try to do

```
for key in search.keys():
    if key not in words:
        words[key] = {k+1: 0 for k in range(num_files)}
    words_ith_val = [words[key][k + 1] for k in range(num_files)]
```

Comment: This is a simplified question, in reality there are hundreds of files.

Comment: @DannyBoy, Now the answer is parametrised on the num_files variable.

Comment: I get an error: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'key' referenced before assignment

Comment: @DannyBoy : in your algorithm is a value of [key for key in search.keys()]

Comment: Sorry I do not follow?

Comment: Thanks it runs now but the list returned contains only 1 item not the full 4?

Comment: @DannyBoy,  maybe the last changes reflect your intention.